# Julia: Is there a way to find the latest possible version number of a package?

Tags: julia

It is common for my install packages to be not at the latest version due to dependency restrictions. However, I would like a way to determine if I have the latest possible version of a package e.g. by looking into the General registry. Is there a programmatic way to achieve that in Julia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this under Julia 1.4.2:

```
julia> using Pkg

julia> function max_ver_number(pkgname::AbstractString)
           path = joinpath(DEPOT_PATH[1], "registries", "General",
                           first(pkgname, 1), pkgname, "Versions.toml")
           maximum(VersionNumber.(keys(Pkg.TOML.parse(read(path, String)))))
       end
max_ver_number (generic function with 1 method)

julia> max_ver_number("DataFrames")
v"0.21.4"

julia> max_ver_number("CSV")
v"0.7.1"
```

This code assumes that before running this you updated the local copy of general registry.

Note that here I assume that only `DEPOT_PATH[1]` is checked (so it is not fully general). For example this will fail for stdlib, e.g.:

```
julia> max_ver_number("Statistics")
ERROR: SystemError: opening file "/home/bkamins/.julia/registries/General/S/Statistics/Versions.toml": No such file or directory
```

However, I assume that for typical use cases what is proposed should be enough.